# To find the number of Elements of order 4 in Galois Field $GF(p^n)^*$,

Tags: finite-fields, cyclic-groups, galois-extensions

If we consider $p$ be a prime number such that $p \pmod4 =3.$ How many elements of order $4$ are in $GF(p^n)^*?$

If modulo were $p \pmod 4 = 1.$ Then I could easily solve the question. Since $GF(p^n)^*$ is isomorphic to $Z_{p^{n}-1}$ which is cyclic. And $4$ divides $p-1$ and can easily show that $4$ divides $p^n-1.$

And using the **Theorem**: If $d$ is the divisor of $n$,  then number of elements of order $d$ in a cyclic group of order $n$ is $\phi(d)$.

So I can say that there are $2$ elements of order $4.$

But above question please provide your hint.

Comment: When $p\equiv 3\pmod4$ the square root of $-1$ is an element of $GF(p^2$ but not an element of $GF(p)$. Therefore $GF(p^n)$ contains the elements of order $4$ if and only if it has a copy of $GF(p^2)$ as a subfield if and only if $2\mid n$. The last equivalence coming from the result that $GF(p^n)$ has a subfield isomorphic to $GF(p^m)$ if and only if $m\mid n$.

Answer (score 4):

The multiplicative group of the field is cyclic of order $p^n-1$. So since $p\equiv 3 \mod 4$, if $n$ is odd then it contains no subgroups of order $4$ by Lagrange and if $n$ is even it contains one subgroup of order $4$ hence $2$ elements of order $4$.

Answer (score 0):

first, we prove 4 | (p^n - 1), p mod 4 = 3, then n must be even:
p mod 4 = 3 ⇒ p = 4k + 3, k ∈ Z\Z-
(4k + 3)^n can be expand by binomial theorem, and only the last term 3^n has no   factor 4, so:
4 | (4k + 3)^n - 1 ⇒ 4 | 3^n - 1 ⇒
induction by n,
base condition:
n = 1 ⇒ 4 ∤ 3 - 1 = 2
inductive hypothesis:
n = 2k + 1 ⇒ 4 ∤ 3^(2k + 1) - 1 ⇒
inductive step:
n = 2k + 3 ⇒
3^n - 1 = 3^(2k + 3) - 1 =
3^(2k + 1)3^2 - 1 =
3^(2k + 1)3^2 - 3^2 + 3^2 - 1 =
(3^(2k + 1) - 1)3^2 + 8
4 | 8 but 4 ∤ 3^2, 4 ∤ 3^(2k + 1) - 1 ⇒ 4 ∤ 3^(2k + 3) - 1
QED.

How many elements of order 4 are in GF(p^n)∗, if p mod 4 = 3?
if n is odd, there are none.
if n is even, we can prove 4 | |GF(p^n)*| = p^n - 1:

GF(p^n) = GF(p)(α) = GF(p^n,*)∪{0} ⇒
GF(p^n,*) = <α,*> ⇒
|GF(p^n,*)| = |<α,*>| = p^n - 1
α^|<α,*>| = α^(p^n - 1) = 1 ⇒
α^k ∈ <α,*>, |α^k,*| = |<a^k,*>| = 4 ⇒
p mod 4 = 3 = -1 ⇒ 4 | (p + 1) ⇒
p mod 4 = 3, 4 | (p^n - 1) ⇒ 2 | n (we have proved it.) ⇒
_n(x) = x^n - 1 = ∏(d | n, _d(x)),
d = 2, _2(x) = x + 1 ⇒
_n(p) = p^n - 1 = (p + 1)*∏(d | n, d ≠ 2, _d(p)) ⇒
4 | (p^n - 1),
QED.
so, we got φ(4) = 2^2 - 2 = 2

Comment: You can use latex in this website, here is basic tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).